# Insertar input en formulario al seleccionar un dato especifico en un select

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Buenos dias tengo la siguiente pregunta tengo un formulario para recolectar cierta informacion y tengo una duda, lograr que al seleccionar un dato en especifico en mi select, me inserte un input nuevo en mi formulario o de alguna forma me abra un modal o un alert para insertar un dato nuevo en ese formulario.

Tengo el siguiente select

Con el siguiente script

```
function NpCorto() {
        var textoNpCorto = $("select#causa").val();

         if (textoNpCorto == "Corto de Material SPMKT") {
            alert ('Seleccionado.'); 
         } else { 
            alert ('Error en la peticion al servidor.');
            };
    };
```

Y aca el select:

```
<select name="causa" id="causa" class="form-control" onchange="NpCorto();" required>
```

Funciona a la perfeccion pero no se si es la manera correcta, por que yo lo que quiero es lograr meter o me aparezca un nuevo input en mi formulario o salga un modal con un input y se meta al formulario.

```
<form action="insertar.php" id="frmpsb" method="POST" role="form" autocomplete="off">
                    <?php
                        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","psb_smt");
                        // Check connection
                        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                        {
                            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                        }
                        $sql="SELECT * FROM psb_smt.psb_employees";
                        $sql1="SELECT * FROM psb_smt.psb_employees";    
                        $QueryNumParts="SELECT * FROM psb_smt.psb_partsproduction"; 
                                $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                                $result1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
                                $QueryResultParts=mysqli_query($con,$QueryNumParts);
                    ?>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Hora</label>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET["line"]?>" name="psb_line" id="psb_line" class="form-control"/>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $idPSB;?>" name="id_psbinfo" id="id_psbinfo" class="form-control"/>
                    <!-- <input type="text" name="IdLineXD" id="IdLineXD" class="form-control"/> -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="serverDate" name="DateTime" class="form-control"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Hour_Psb" id="Hours_psb" class="form-control"/>
                    <select name="psb_hr" id="psb_hr" class="form-control" onchange='cambioOpciones();' required/>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
                        <option value="04">06:40 - 07:00</option>
                        <option value="05">07:00 - 08:00</option>
                        <option value="06">08:00 - 09:00</option>
                        <option value="07">09:00 - 10:00</option>
                        <option value="08">10:00 - 11:00</option>
                        <option value="09">11:00 - 12:00</option>
                        <option value="10">12:00 - 13:00</option>
                        <option value="11">13:00 - 14:00</option>
                        <option value="12">14:00 - 15:00</option>
                        <option value="13">15:00 - 16:10</option>
                        <option value="14">16:10 - 17:00</option>
                        <option value="15">17:00 - 18:00</option>
                        <option value="16">18:00 - 19:00</option>
                        <option value="17">19:00 - 20:00</option>
                        <option value="18">20:00 - 21:00</option>
                        <option value="19">21:00 - 22:16</option>
                        <option value="20">22:16 - 23:00</option>
                        <option value="21">23:00 - 00:00</option>
                        <option value="22">00:00 - 01:00</option>
                        <option value="23">01:00 - 02:00</option>
                        <option value="24">02:00 - 03:00</option>
                        <option value="25">03:00 - 04:00</option>
                        <option value="26">04:00 - 05:00</option>
                        <option value="27">05:00 - 06:00</option>
                        <option value="28">06:00 - 06:40</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Scrap</label>
                    <input name="scrap" type="number" id="scrap" class="form-control" disabled required />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Minutos</label>
                    <select name="psb_min" id="psb_min" class="form-control" onChange='calcula();' disabled required />
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Numero de parte</label>
                    <select type="text" id="psb_np" name="psb_np" class='form-control' autocomplete="off" onChange="buscarNP();" disabled required />
                        <option value disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
                            <?php
                            try {
                                while ($rows = $QueryResultParts->fetch_assoc()){
                                printf ("<option>".$rows["number_part"]."</option>");
                                }
                                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                            echo $e ->getMessage();
                                }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Produccion</label>
                    <input type="number" name="psb_produc" id="psb_produc" onkeypress='return validaNumericos(event)' class="form-control" onkeyup='calcula();' disabled required />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Auxiliar</label>
                    <select type="text" id="busqueda" name="id_employee" class='form-control' autocomplete="off" onChange="buscar();" disabled required />
                        <option value disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
                            <?php
                            try {
                                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                                printf ("<option>".$row["nombre"]."</option>");
                                }
                                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                            echo $e ->getMessage();
                                }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    <label>Empatarollos</label>
                    <select type="text" id="busquedaemp" name="busquedaemp" class='form-control' autocomplete="off" onChange="buscaremp();" disabled required />
                        <option value disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
                            <?php
                            try {
                                while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
                                printf ("<option>".$row["nombre"]."</option>");
                                }
                                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                            echo $e ->getMessage();
                                }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                        <input type="hidden" name="psb_rates" id="psb_rates" class="form-control" />
                        <div id="PartNumberSearch" style="display: none;"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="psb_tpt" id="resultado" class="form-control" />  
                        <div id="resultadoBusqueda" style="display: none;"></div>
                        <div id="resultadoEmpatarollo" style="display: none;"></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm py-1" type="submit">Guardar datos</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm py-1" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
              </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: A ver, para que quieres que cuando haya cambio en el select, te agregue un input a tu formuario? con que finalidad, a ver si te puedo dar una mejor idea.

Comment: Por que por ejemplo cuando alguien seleccione que hay un corto de material, me aprezca un nuevo input y me ingresen de que numero de parte esta corto y saber el dato especifico pero solo con esa opcion, pues es la que requiero de todos los select.

Comment: Añade al post tu formulario para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Ya lo agregue al codigo es algo extenso.

Comment: Mi consejo es que seria mas facil y rapido que lo hagas con input radio y jquery, asi sengun lo que el usuario selecione muestro o oculta el input del form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buena lo que hice para solucionar mi problema fue lo siguiente, en mi formulario agrege un div oculto de la siguiente manera.

```
<div id="divEle" style="display:none;"><date stuff>
<div class="form-group">
<label style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">Numero de parte de material corto</label>
<input type="text" name="npcorto" id="npcorto" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

Con el siguiente script:

```
function NpCorto() {
    var textoNpCorto = $("select#causa").val();

     if (textoNpCorto == "Corto de Material SPMKT") {
            alert('Ingresar el numero de material corto.');
            $("#divEle").toggle();
     } else { 
            $("#divEle").hide();
        };
};
```

En el select coloque el onchange con el nombre de la funcion asi:

```
<select name="causa" id="causa" class="form-control" onchange="NpCorto();" required>
```

Y ya de esta manera resolvi yo mismo lo que estaba buscando, gracias.